# C++ Binary Search Tree and Pointers

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

could you please tell me why the call of the method `binaryTree.Exists(5);` says that "5 doesn't exist in the binary tree"? when debugging, it's like when trying to access the node where 5 is inserted doesn't exist anymore. i don't see why. thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Node
{
    private:
        int _value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

    public:
        Node(int value):_value(value), left(NULL), right(NULL)
        {
        }
        Node* returnLeftChild()
        {
            return left;
        }
        Node* returnRightChild()
        {
            return right;
        }
        void setLeftChild(Node* l)
        {
            left=l;
        }
        void setRightChild(Node* r)
        {
            right=r;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            return _value;
        }
};

class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        Node parent;
        void AddToOneTree(Node* parent, int value)
        {
            if (value==parent->getValue())
            {
                return;
            }
            if (value>parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnRightChild()==NULL)
                {
                    Node newNode(value);
                    parent->setRightChild(&newNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToOneTree(parent->returnRightChild(), value);
                }
            }
            if (value<parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnLeftChild()==NULL)
                {
                    Node newNode(value);
                    parent->setLeftChild(&newNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToOneTree(parent->returnLeftChild(), value);
                }
            }           
        }

        void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool found)
        {
            if (value>parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnRightChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnRightChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        found= true;
                        goto HERE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnRightChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (value<parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnLeftChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnLeftChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        found= true;
                        goto HERE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnLeftChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
            HERE:;
        }

    public:
        BinaryTree(int parentValue):parent(parentValue)
        {   
        }

        void Add(int value)
        {
            AddToOneTree(&parent, value);
        }

        void Exists(int value)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (parent.getValue()==value)
            {
                cout << value << " exists in the Binary Tree." << endl;
            }
            else{
                LookForValue(&parent, value, found);
                if (found)
                {
                    cout << value << " exists in the Binary Tree." << endl;
                }else
                {
                    cout << value << " doesn't exist in the Binary Tree." << endl;
                }
            }
        }

};

int main()
{
    BinaryTree binaryTree(9);
    binaryTree.Add(5);
    binaryTree.Add(5);

    binaryTree.Exists(9);
    binaryTree.Exists(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least function `AddToOneTree` is wrong and is the reason of **undefined behaviour** of the program

For example in this code block

```
if (parent->returnRightChild()==NULL)
{
    Node newNode(value);
    parent->setRightChild(&newNode);
    return;
}
```

you create a local variable `newNode` and its address asign to the pointer of right child. However as the variable is local it is destroyed after the control leaves the code block and the corresponding pointer in the tree will be invalid.

You need to dynamically allocate nodes and add them to the tree.

A better design is when the class `BinaryTree` contains a ponter to the head of the tree. Declare data member parent like

```
class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        Node *parent;
             ^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

and correspondingly rewrite the class.:)

Comment: Did not see the undefined behaviour, upvote deserved. I bet that this answer should be the accepted one

Comment: @LBesancon Thanks. You are a kind person.:)

Comment: It's not kindness. Among all the problems that others (and I) reported, this is probably the biggest one and we failed to notice it so this definitely should be the accepted answer. OP should have spent more time reading answers instead of jumping to the first one that may solve momentarily the problem but still fails to grasps the undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this string:

```
void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool found)
```

to this:

```
void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool &found)
```

or just set return value to `bool` in `LookForValue` function and write something like this:

```
found = LookForValue(&parent, value, found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code.

The first one is that the boolean found is never returned by the `LookForValue` function. You can either change bool found to bool & found so that you do not have to return anything or change the return type of `LookForValue` to `bool` in which case you'll need to change your code to something like this:

```
bool LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool found)
{
            if (value>parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnRightChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnRightChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        return true ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnRightChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (value<parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnLeftChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnLeftChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        return true ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnLeftChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

If you change the return type please also think about changing one line in your `Exists` function just after the `else`:

```
found = LookForValue(&parent, value, found);
```

I haven't tested the code yet so there might be other issues still.

The next time you face such an issue, I suggest trying to use gdb as it will probably help in detecting what your code is really doing so that you can figure out what may be wrong. For instance here, you could have seen that the found was never set to true in your `Exists` function just by "printing" step by step the value of your `found` variable.

Also, I think the way you designed your classes is not really good. Parent should be a pointer, pointing to the root of the tree. I would suggest a complete re-designing of your code. You can find some good implementations online that you can be your code upon.

Finally the goto is definitely a bad idea... I would get rid of that too.

Comment: I agree, using goto is a bad idea. what do you mean by gdb?

Comment: Here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger. You might also want to change the design of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool found)
```

You are passing `found` by value. That means the value will be copied. When you change `found` inside of the method `LookForValue` you are only changing this copy.

```
void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool& found)
```

This will pass found by reference, so if you change it inside of `LookForValue` the original in the `Exists`  method will be changed as well.

You can also just return a bool value like this:

```
bool LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool &found)
```

And then just write `return true;` instead of

```
found= true;
goto HERE;
```

That way you also get rid of the goto.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone. i've changed passing found by reference and allocated memeory using "new" for new nods.This now works!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Node
{
    private:
        int _value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

    public:
        Node(int value):_value(value), left(NULL), right(NULL)
        {
        }
        Node* returnLeftChild()
        {
            return left;
        }
        Node* returnRightChild()
        {
            return right;
        }
        void setLeftChild(Node* l)
        {
            left=l;
        }
        void setRightChild(Node* r)
        {
            right=r;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            return _value;
        }
};

class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        Node parent;
        void AddToOneTree(Node* parent, int value)
        {
            if (value==parent->getValue())
            {
                return;
            }
            if (value>parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnRightChild()==NULL)
                {
                    Node* newNode=new Node(value);
                    parent->setRightChild(newNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToOneTree(parent->returnRightChild(), value);
                }
            }
            if (value<parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnLeftChild()==NULL)
                {
                    Node* newNode=new Node(value);
                    parent->setLeftChild(newNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToOneTree(parent->returnLeftChild(), value);
                }
            }           
        }


        void LookForValue(Node* parent, int value, bool &found)
        {
            if (value>parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnRightChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnRightChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        found= true;
                        goto HERE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnRightChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (value<parent->getValue())
            {
                if (parent->returnLeftChild()!=NULL)
                {
                    if (parent->returnLeftChild()->getValue()==value)
                    {
                        found= true;
                        goto HERE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LookForValue(parent->returnLeftChild(), value, found);
                    }
                }
            }
            HERE:;
        }

    public:
        BinaryTree(int parentValue):parent(parentValue)
        {   
        }

        void Add(int value)
        {
            AddToOneTree(&parent, value);
        }

            void Exists(int value)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (parent.getValue()==value)
            {
                cout << value << " exists in the Binary Tree." << endl;
            }
            else{
                LookForValue(&parent, value, found);
                if (found)
                {
                    cout << value << " exists in the Binary Tree." << endl;
                }else
                {
                    cout << value << " doesn't exist in the Binary Tree." << endl;
                }
            }
        }

};

int main()
{
    BinaryTree binaryTree(9);
    binaryTree.Add(5);
    binaryTree.Add(6);
    binaryTree.Add(1);
    binaryTree.Add(15);
    binaryTree.Add(13);
    binaryTree.Add(2);
    binaryTree.Add(2);
    binaryTree.Add(0);
    binaryTree.Add(4);

    binaryTree.Exists(9);
    binaryTree.Exists(5);
    binaryTree.Exists(6);
    binaryTree.Exists(1);
    binaryTree.Exists(15);
    binaryTree.Exists(13);
    binaryTree.Exists(2);
    binaryTree.Exists(2);
    binaryTree.Exists(0);
    binaryTree.Exists(4);
    binaryTree.Exists(11);

    binaryTree.Exists(412);

    binaryTree.Exists(40);


}
```

Comment: Still some issues with your code, see my post for explanations ;). Glad that it works nonetheless :). And usually, after accepting an answer, OP should not post is whole code as an answer too ;)